# Django Error: 'bool' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, django, view, django-models, model

I'm getting the following Django error when I add a filter onto my view.

```
'bool' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Here's the View, and if I remove `.filter(Proposal.user == request.user)` then everything works fine. Additionally if I print `Proposal.user` and `request.user` they are the same.

```
# views.py
def my_proposal_list(request):
    response = {}
    response['proposal_list'] = Proposal.objects.all().filter(Proposal.user == request.user)
    return render(request, "my-proposals.html", response)
```

And here is the Proposal Model. It's supposed to be returning and filtering:

```
# Models.py
class Proposal(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Name Your Proposal')
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, help_text='Who is this proposal for? What does it do?')
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s %s" % (self.title, self.user)
```

What am I doing wrong? I don't know which Boolean object it's referencing. Your help would be greatly helpful! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a single `=` sign for `filter()` arguments:

Replace:

```
.filter(Proposal.user == request.user)
```

with:

```
.filter(user=request.user)
```

Note that you can also omit `Proposal.` and use just `user` here.

Also, there is no need for `all()` since you are using `filter()` afterwards:

```
response['proposal_list'] = Proposal.objects.filter(user=request.user)
```

Comment: That was it! It's always something that I've tried before (but must have done incorrectly). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You've got double `=` that is throwing off your code.

Change it to:

```
response['proposal_list'] = Proposal.objects.all().filter(Proposal.user=request.user)
```